# The proper way to update data-model array used by UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am guessing that we should tend to use immutable array for our data-model array that is used by `UITableView`. Readings about this are very different over the internet. I would say  that this can prevent an array being modified while tableview displaying data. For example, `numberOfRowsInSection:` method might be problematic if the above happens, right (still I can't really think of scenario how this can happen in a real world even if I know it is theoretically possible)?

Now, in `commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method, I am doing this (messagesArray is mutable):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    Message *message = messageArray[indexPath.row];
    [messagesArray removeObject:message];
    [self.messageTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

rather than(having `messagesArray` immutable):

```
 NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:messagesArray];
 [temp  removeObject:message];
 messagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];
```

The latter code is what I had to do if the `messageArray` was immutable.

Now I have two questions...IMO (correct me if I am wrong), removing an object from an array in both ways in a method above have the same effect. messagesArray end up with one element removed. That's it... But doing things like in a latter example, allows me to have immutable data-model array.

Can somebody comment what is actually a preferred way (or I can say proper way?) to update data-model array after cell is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to have a mutable array but make it private. Then if another class needs to change the array you can provide an `add()` method and a `delete()` method. Both of which would have the responsibility of updating both the array and the table view.

Comment: It is private already actually... I am more worried in which situations some mess might happen if I keep it mutable...

Comment: If you change the array, regardless of mutability, the table view has to be updated with it or you will be seeing bad data and could potentially crash (index out of bounds error when you scroll to the end, for example)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter from the table view's side what structure your data source is using to organize the data. The table view isn't accessing that structure directly. It asks the data source for the pieces that it needs when it needs them.

Now, you're right: you can screw up your table view by changing the backing data. But that happens regardless of the mutability of the particular collection. Your immutable array snippet does the same thing: the table view doesn't know that anything's changed until you **notify** it with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:animated`. Reloading the table view when the data source updates is **essential**, no matter what your data source is doing internally.

Comment: Okay I get now what you guys are saying. Still, I think that `reloadData` is not needed in the case above, because `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` will update tableview automatically, right? I mean, I change data-model array, then I call deleteRowsAtIndexPaths, and tableview will be updated automatically without a need to send reloadData?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're absolutely right about that. I didn't read your code as thoroughly as I should.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 

UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        //1. remove data from model
        dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        //2. remove row from view
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Yes! Reload data is not needed when you implement swipe to delete! `UITableView` takes care of it. You only need to update your dataSource